# Передача value из input в input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется каталог товаров. У каждого товара есть кнопка заказать, по нажатию на которую появляется форма обратной связи.

Необходимо название товара передать в форму обратной связи.

Каким образом можно передать?

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Подробнее, пожалуйста, что за форма обратной связи,  как вы ее открываете, покажите код, как вы пытались это сделать, покажите верстку формы, название у вас в `input`?

Comment: Выбрать донора, выбрать акцептора, присвоить значение `value` первого к последнему. Всё :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('.products').onclick = function(e) {
  if(e.target.classList.contains('product__order')) {
  var priceValue = e.target
    .closest('.product')
    .querySelector('.product__price')
    .innerHTML;

    document.querySelector('.form input').value = priceValue;
    document.querySelector('.form').classList.add('form--open')
  }
}
```

```css
.product {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.product__price {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.form {
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.form--open {
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class=products>
  <div class=product>
    <div class=product__price>$1000.50</div>
    <button class=product__order>Order</button>
  </div>
  <div class=product>
    <div class=product__price>$1100.50</div>
    <button class=product__order>Order</button>
  </div>
  <div class=product>
    <div class=product__price>$1200.50</div>
    <button class=product__order>Order</button>
  </div>
  <div class=product>
    <div class=product__price>$1300.50</div>
    <button class=product__order>Order</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class=form>
  <form>
    <input type=text />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Зря ответили, но приятно видеть использование БЭМ. -1 + 1 = 0, ничего не поставлю.

Comment: @Other -1 + 1 = 0 это откуда математика?

Comment: Мой голос для минуса этого ответа и для плюса подрались и помножились на ноль. Намекнул что я поставил бы минус, но БЭМ растопило моё сердце :)

Comment: Напишите тогда за что минус хотели, может я смогу всё исправить )

Comment: За ответ на вопрос без какой-либо попытки автора помочь самому себе.

Comment: @Sasha Omelchenko, спасибо за Вашу помощь!  Только код Ваш работает только для одного товара, если к примеру создать еще один блок товара, то цена уже не хочет в инпут подставляться

Comment: @АлексейЯрыгин переписал с делегированием событий, см. обновленный ответ.

Comment: @Sasha Omelchenko, спасибо большое! Очень помогли!